# Push All Local Files of Repository to Remote

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have local repository (managed with Git) which contains all the older versions of my project and now I want to upload it to GitLab (GL) and SourceTree (ST). I created my project in the GL with link like `https://gitlab.com/myusername/myproject`.

I used ST to push all my branches and tags to the origin i.e. GL repo `https://gitlab.com/myusername/myproject.git`.

To verify, I cloned the repo in a demo local repo and compared the sizes and number of files of original loacal repo & demo repo and found out that there is huge difference between the two.

I doubt that files of only latest commit or checked out branch  and history of revisions are uploaded to GL (and not local files related to older revisions/commits which are present in hidden folder in the local repo because I can't see them on the server in my remote repo).

How can I sync/upload all files of all commits to the remote so that I can backup of my repo in case anything happens to my local repo.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: Git does not push *files*. Git pushes *commits*. Every commit has a full snapshot of every file, and a commit drags its history (previous commits) along with it. So if you push your new commits—the ones you made since you got all the existing commits from the GitLab repository—they now have all their original commits (which you also have) plus all your new commits (which you also have). Everyone has everything; that's how Git works.

Comment: Whenever you select a commit to *check out*, Git will *remove* from your working area, all the files that were copied out of the old commit, and plug in instead all the files that go with the commit you've just selected. When you switch to another commit, Git removes those files and puts in the other commit's files. But every commit holds every file (that was put in it when it was made), frozen for all time.

Comment: Note that the files in your working tree are *not in Git*. They may have just *come out of Git* (out of a commit), but as you make changes to them, Git is entirely unaware of what you're doing. Eventually you must tell Git to re-scan your updated files and prepare and then make a new commit, and only then does Git store a new snapshot (of *all* files, not just the ones you changed). The snapshots are in a frozen-for-all-time format with files compressed and *de-duplicated* so they don't waste disk space.

Comment: You mean if I clone this repo and checkout older version from cloned repo, it will work exactly the same as that of checking out from the original local repo?

Comment: But why is ther huge difference in number of files and size of repo's? I was actually alarmed by that.

Comment: Moreover there is no git files (which have snapshot of revision) on the server. Sorry if this is too basic for git because I am new to this.

Comment: Yes: if you clone the repository, you get all the commits (and no branches, and then your Git software creates one branch in your new clone—so don't go by *branches*, go by *commits*). The repository is a big database of commits, which get shared across clones (plus a smaller database of names that help you find commits; the names don't get shared the same way).

Comment: Is size and number of files difference between local and remote repository
 normal?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're *measuring* the size, but the size of the database is in a count of objects, which can be either "loose" (one per file) or "packed" (many in one file) (and in some cases some objects are unused, eventually to be deleted). Cloning results in a single pack file, which will generally take a lot less disk space than many loose objects, but will still contain the same set of objects. Packs accumulate, which will consume *more* disk space, until they are "repacked" and then the disk space drops. Databases are hard to characterize.